# Как реализовать дополнительную информацию при наведение мышки на кнопку в tkinter?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, label, bind

Как реализовать дополнительную информацию при наведение мышки на `Button` или на `Label` в tkinter? Каждый по крайней мере видел это хоть раз, на примере Team Viewer:

(Без наведения мышки, ничего не происходит и не появляется)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

А теперь с наведением мышки :

(Появилось окно с информацией)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Может есть какой нибудь метод или функция уже готовая?

Comment: Надеюсь понятно объяснил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это называется «всплывающая подсказка» (tooltip):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter as tk
from idlelib.tooltip import ListboxToolTip

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Hover')
button = tk.Button(text='button with tooltip')
button.pack()
ListboxToolTip(button, ['tooltip', 'text'])
root.mainloop()
```

[image: screencast tooltip on hover button]

Связанный вопрос: [How do I display tooltips in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3221956/4279)

Answer (score 1):

В версии idlelib.tooltip, которая установлена у меня, отсутствует класс ListboxToolTip, но есть класс Hovertip, который выполняет ту же функцию. Может быть кому-то пригодится эта информация.

```
import tkinter as tk
from idlelib.tooltip import Hovertip

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Hover')
button = tk.Button(text='button with tooltip')
button.pack()
Hovertip(button, "tooltip text", hover_delay=100)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Эту информацию перенесите в [тело самого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1299761/edit), а комментарий удалите.